# Specify makefile location to link libraries

Tags: linker, makefile

I recently stumbled upon this in a project I'm working on. In package `A`, there is a required configuration option `--package-B-makefile-location` from which `A`'s makefile borrows variable values.

Is this a common design pattern which has merit? It seems to me that `B`'s package source is as important as its binary for compiling `A`. Might there be reasons I wouldn't want to tamper with it?

Thanks,

Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is far from unheard of for one package to need other packages pre-installed, and you have to specify those locations.

For example, building GCC (4.5.2), you need to specify the locations of the GMP, MPFR and MPC libraries if they won't be found by default.

Complex systems which are extensible - Perl, Apache, Tcl/Tk, PHP - provide configuration data to their users in various ways (Config.pm for Perl, apxs for Apache, etc), but that configuration data is crucial to dependent modules.

My suspicion is that your Package A needs some of the configuration data related to Package B, but there isn't a fully-fledged system for providing it.  As a workaround, Package A needs to see the configuration data encapsulated in the makefile.

It is not common to need the makefile; it is not uncommon to need some information about other packages.

Comment: If the only thing that I'm after is a shared object library, do you think it's safe to assume I can start ripping out this makefile dependency?

Comment: @ajwood: probably.  If your Package A just needs to know where the shared library and header for Package B are installed, then have a way to configure that location for Package A, and use a suitable default if the user doesn't specify it - maybe `/usr/local` (meaning the header would be expected in `/usr/local/include` and the library in `/usr/local/lib`).

Answer (score 0):

It's a common and useful design pattern as far as it goes, but it can be abused like any other.

I'm not sure I understand the second part of your question, but if the makefiles are well designed then any change you make to B's makefiles which doesn't break B won't break A either.